# Antlr4: Generating a Lisp s-expression style output from an expression

Tags: c#, antlr4, antlr4cs

Referring to this [link](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction). It shows how to create a lisp style s-expression
from any infix expression on Antlr3.

I am using Antlr4 and it doesn't seem to work on it.

Can someone please suggest me some way to achieve it ?

`2x+3x^5` to `(+ (* 2 x) (* 3 (^ x 5)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite Rules are no longer available in ANTLR4 so you will have to do some other way.
A possible approach is the the following:

1. define a class hierarchy that models the entities of your (new) tree: this will be the object model of your alternative Abstract Syntax Tree;
2. implement a visitor (or a listener) that traverses the parse tree created by the ANTLR4 parser and generates an instance of your AST;

[Here](https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/antlr4-project-with-maven-tutorial-episode-3/) there's an example of this process

Comment: I wrote a new visitor class where I wrote methods to collect details as List<object>.